# Ec2 instance getting terminated instantly in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created a simple JSON template for launching an EC2 instance using CloudFormation. The JSON code works for RedHat `ami-2051294a` (in `us-east-1 region`) but does not work for Amazon Linux `ami-0b33d91d`.

What could be the issue?

```
  "Resources": {
    "Ec2Instance" :{
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "Tags": [
          { "Key" : "Name" , "Value" : "BIP-Spark" } 
           ],
        "KeyName": { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "BipDevInstanceType" },
        "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "NATAMI" },
        "IamInstanceProfile" : { "Ref": "RoleName" },
        "BlockDeviceMappings" : [ { 
           "DeviceName" : "/dev/sda1",
           "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "30", "VolumeType": "gp2" } 
            },
           {
           "DeviceName" : "/dev/sdb",
           "Ebs" : { "VolumeSize" : "30", "VolumeType": "gp2" }
           }
        ],
        "NetworkInterfaces" : [ {
           "GroupSet": [ "sg-***" ],
           "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "SubnetID" },
           "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
           "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
           "DeviceIndex":"0" }
         ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! your sample code is rather large -- are you able to reduce it down to show the specific issue? That is, remove all unnecessary bits that don't lead directly the to problem you are experiencing. Also, what do you mean by "does not work" -- does the instance enter the Pending or Running state? What error is displayed in the CloudFormation "Events" console?

Comment: The events console status shows Create_complete. The ec2 console shows  pending and then is stopped. I tested on ec2 console and the ec2-instance is up using the ami-0b33d91d  but only when i use cloud formation the ec2 instance is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both AMIs launched perfectly well for me.

Here is the minimal version of the template that I used to successfully launch an Amazon EC2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI `ami-0b33d91d`:

```
{  
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",

  "Resources": {
    "Ec2Instance" :{
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
        "ImageId" : "ami-0b33d91d",
        "NetworkInterfaces" : [ {
           "GroupSet": [ "sg-xxxxxxxx" ],
           "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxxxxx",
           "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
           "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
           "DeviceIndex":"0" }
         ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The instance successfully entered the **Running** state and kept running correctly.

It is likely that one of your manually-entered parameters was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks John, :)  it worked but i am not sure what was wrong earlier. but it did work for me with your code.